# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload file to Google Cloud Storage using Java App Engine. Very standard code using GcsService.

The libraries I use: **appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.6.3** and **appengine-gcs-client-0.5.**

When I try to run my code I get next exception:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
                              com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter
```

I obviously checked the jars and the class is missing, but also I can't find any missing import.

Probably I use wrong package versions or miss something.

Comment: What is trying to call that class?

Comment: what's your ide/setup?

Comment: I run on intelliJ IDEA ide. I solved this problem, it was caused by old API version, now when I'm running with appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.25 I pass this step by get another exception:    ep 02, 2015 10:04:37 AM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFO: RetryHelper(904.4 ?s, 1 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@7f394a9d): Attempt #1 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException], sleeping for 11 ms